# In python3.7 hashlib, the results obtained from the same calculation twice are different

Tags: python-3.x

```
import hashlib

# Create md5 object
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update("Hello!".encode("utf-8"))
print(md5.hexdigest())  # out:952d2c56d0485958336747bcdd98590d

# No md5 object
hashlib.md5().update("Hello!".encode("utf-8"))
print(hashlib.md5().hexdigest())  # out:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Hi! Why the two outputs are different? Who can tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "the same calculation":  you print the `hexdigest()` of an "empty" md5() instance and compare it to the `hexdigest()` of a modified one.

---

The command `hashlib.md5()` returns a `md5()` instance. Storing it into a variable lets you modify its internal state using

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update("Hello!".encode("utf-8"))
```

and produces a different output then that of an "empty" one:

```
 # "empty" md5 object stored as variable and directly printed are identical
 md52 =  hashlib.md5()
 print(md52.hexdigest())           # out: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
 print(hashlib.md5().hexdigest())  # out: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Using

```
hashlib.md5().update("Hello!".encode("utf-8"))
```

creates a `md5()` instance and updates it to something different ... and throws it away.